# Prove $aH=bH$ implies $Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that with $H$ a subgroup of $G$ that: 
$$aH=bH \implies Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$$
which I tried by doing the following:

---

If $aH=bH$ means that:
$ x\in aH \iff x\in bH $ then we can decompose it into:
$$ x\in aH \iff \exists h_1\in H:a\circ h_1=x\;\; \text{  and  } \;\; x\in bH \iff \exists h_2\in H:b\circ h_2=x $$
which would mean:
$$  a\circ h_1=x=b\circ h_2 \;\; \iff\;\; h_2^{-1}\circ b^{-1}=h_1^{-1}\circ a^{-1}$$

But $Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$ depends on showing that: $$Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1} \iff \exists h_3,h_4\in H : h_3a^{-1}=x=h_4b^{-1} $$
Thus we can demonstrate the existence from $h_2^{-1}\circ b^{-1}=h_1^{-1}\circ a^{-1}$ since we could just let $h_4=h_2^{-1}$ and $h_3=h_1^{-1}$.

---

I'm not sure if this is correct though, I feel like it may be incorrect to find the values of $h_3$ and $h_4$ in the way I did. I've seen another question that proves this in not quite the same way but I'm curious to know whether this is incorrect, and if it is, how could I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You don't make a clear connection between the statement $aH = bH$ and your statement on $x \in aH$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how do you mean? Thanks

Comment: The statement $$a\circ h_1=b\circ h_2 \Leftrightarrow h_2^{-1} \circ b^{-1} = h_1^{-1} \circ a^{-1}$$ is always true (just take inverses on each side of the equals sign), so it doesn't depend on anything that comes before it in your proof ... and you shouldn't be able to conclude $Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$ from this equivalence either.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's what I was worried about. Is it salvageable in anyway or just completely wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jay you don't quite make clear how you link the two statements $a\circ h_1 = \cdots$ and $Ha^{-1} = \cdots$. You DO have to be careful, as they are certainly not the same $x$. Nevertheless all the ideas are there. You can link the first and second parts by observing that $x\in aH \iff x^{-1} \in Ha^{-1}$.

Comment: @Jay: What I'm getting at (but perhaps phrasing it too sarcastically) is that when you write something like "this means: $P\Leftrightarrow Q$", it is not clear whether you mean "this means that $P$ is true, and by the way $P$ is equivalent to $Q$", or "this means that $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent" -- and this confusion makes it quite difficult to get the drift of your proof.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How would you write it to make it clearer? At the moment I'm self-teaching so I haven't had anyone to give feedback on my proof writing technique which makes it hard to get better at it. Again thanks for the help!

Comment: I would write something like: Assume $x\in Ha^{-1}$, so $x=ha^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$. Therefore $x^{-1}=ah^{-1}$, so $x^{-1}\in aH$. Since $aH=bH$ we have $x^{-1}=bh'$ for some $h'\in H$, and so $x=(h')^{-1}b^{-1}$, and therefore $x\in Hb^{-1}$. So $Ha^{-1}\subseteq Hb^{-1}$, and the reverse inclusion follows in the same way.

Comment: @Mathmo123 that makes sense, it seems that's why I felt something wasn't quite right, it was the connection between the two. I've been thinking about this for a little bit and using what you said would this be a correct proof: $ x\in Ha^{-1} \iff x^{-1}\in aH  \iff x^{-1}\in bH \iff x\in Hb^{-1}$ (where the second iff is because $aH=bH$) so $Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$. If so it's much shorter than my initial attempt! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$aH=bH\implies (aH)^{-1}=(bH)^{-1}$
and  $(aH)^{-1}=H^{-1}a^{-1}=Ha^{-1}$ since, by definition of a subgroup, $H=H^{-1}$.